# Angular ng build --watch seems to be broken in angular version 11

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr, angular-ivy

During development of angular libraries, I build the libraries on-the-fly using the `ng build <lib> --watch`. Setup is according to the official Angular docs at: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries  I am symlinking the libraries into my project with `npm link`. My angular 11 project is compiled using the Ivy compiler. My library is using the View  Engine compiler. The `ng serve` command uses `ngcc` to add the Ivy specific extras to the library (the build artifact in `dist`)

However, this approach does not work anymore for a new Angular 11 project. Everytime that the library gets rebuilt by the watcher, the application served by `ng serve` loses track and needs to be restarted afresh.

I tried downgrading angular to 10.x and sychronized the typescript compiler version in the library and the application project.

Restarting the `ng serve` of the project leads to: `Tried to overwrite *.component.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.` all the time. Only thing that helps in that case is restarting the `ng build <lib> --watch` process.

It seems to me that the in-limbo status of Ivy has thoroughly broken the library development experience using `npm link`.

Has anyone ideas about what has changed in Angular 11 that causes this problem?

Comment: Adding the out param could be a fix for it. `ng build --watch -o dist/`. Let's give it a try! Thank you :)

Comment: It seems the -o (--output-path) has only recently been added. My library project is still angular-cli version 10.2.3 and does not support the -o flag unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a nice solution that did not work for Angular 11, however, after downgrading to Angular 10, this works. The idea is to add an extra build configuration to the library for compiling in Ivy mode. Even `ng build <lib> --watch` is possible with this approach.

The solution is described here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33395#issuecomment-693306453